# exiting threads on keyboardInterrupt in python

Tags: python, multithreading, scapy

I am implementing a multithreaded network scanner in python using scapy. I want to exit all the threads on keyboardInterrupt. I have managed to make upto the following code, but not all threads are exiting on the exception raised. I have the following code that deals with thread and catches the exception.
thanks

Comment: You really think someone is gonna read your wall of code?

Comment: It really doesn't matter, if one understands what I am stuck with mentioned in my question...

Answer (score 1):

This is just a small note.
Normally the `KeyboardInterrupt` will be raise in the main thread, thus enabling you do to something along the lines of:

```
import threading
main = None
for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t.name == 'MainThread':
        main = t
while main.isAlive():
    ...
```

Which would break the loop whenever the main thread dies.
You could also enumerate the number of threads from the main loop and kill the main process and effectively kill all threads using this main-thread check.

Or you could have an error-flag to which all threads could listen to.
Once an exception has been raised, the error flag would indicate to all other threads that an error has occured and it's time to shut down.

Comment: thanks for the note, I've implemented error-flag method in my code too. Finally, I debugged it and is working fine now.

Comment: @devilfox glad to hear, also the code i posted would obviously go into your sub-threads :)